# How can I pass this variable and check if it matches?

Tags: php, variables, get, isset

How can I correct/simplify this and put it in an array?

A link is passing: somelink.php?w=a (or b,c,d)

I want the page (somelink.php) to determine if "w" is set, and if set and the var matches, include the specified page.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['w'])&&($GET['w'] == "a")){include("1.htm");}
if(isset($_GET['w'])&&($GET['w'] == "b")){include("2.htm");}
if(isset($_GET['w'])&&($GET['w'] == "c")){include("3.htm");}
if(isset($_GET['w'])&&($GET['w'] == "d")){include("4.htm");}
else{include("1.htm");}
?>
```

Comment: Basically, this is being used for a dynamic amount of links with the "w" variable differing for each (a,b,c,x,y,z etc) and corresponding to  a different page (a.htm, b.htm, c.htm, x.htm, y.htm, z.htm etc) within a side navigation bar to tell the container page to include the respective content.

I am sorry if I am not making sense. I am dyslexic and this just does my head in, but I am trying.

Comment: if you are getting to Z i would stop this approach and start looking at a CMS using a db. Your current approach is ok for a small number of files, but sucks for a large number

Comment: the number of links is less than 10, but can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:

```
$w = $_GET['w'];
if(isset($w)) {
    switch(strtolower($w)) {
        case "a":
            include("1.htm");
        break;
        case "b":
            include("2.htm");
        break;
        case "c":
            include("3.htm");
        break;
        case "d":
            include("4.htm");
        break;
        default:
            include("not-found.htm");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create a `Notice: undefined variable w` when `w` is not set.

Comment: it works.. sort of.. but is only pulling the default (not-found.htm) each time, and not any of the other links. despite the variable in the URI. (page.htm?w=a)

Comment: @AdamRoper Ok, I've updated the main answer, try that.

Comment: Hooray! It works perfectly! You are an absolute gem! :p Thank you so very much!

Comment: Thank you to everyone who made an effort to answer. While I am sure there were multiple ways of doing this that would have worked, I have chosen Dylan's response as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a switch statement:

```
if(isset($_GET['w']))
{
    switch($_GET['w'])
    {
        case 'a':    include("1.html");   break;
        case 'b':    include("2.html");   break;
        case 'c':    include("3.html");   break;
        case 'd':    include("4.html");   break;
        default:     include("1.html");   break;
    }
} else {
    include("1.html");
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! I am assuming I would need to unset the variable each time also?

Comment: Shouldn't need to unset anything :) Its up to you whether you do or not.

Comment: @AdamRoper what var did you want to unset? and why?

Comment: its ok. it was just me trying to wrap my head around it (and failing).

Answer (score 1):

how about a simple array

```
$x=array('a'=>'1.html','b'=>'2.html');
```

then

```
include $x[$GET['w']];
```

Comment: This would not work if `w` is not set, or if the value of `w` is not in the array.

Comment: yup i know, its not a complete answer, just my preferred approach

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['w'])){
    switch($_GET['w']){
        case "a":
            include("1.htm");
        break;
        case "b":
            include("2.htm");
        break;
        case "c":
            include("3.htm");
        break;
        case "d":
            include("4.htm");
        break;
    }
}
```

But I wouldn't do it that way. I'd make it so that the name of the page corresponds to the value being retrieved from the $_GET variable. That way you could do something like this.

```
if(!empty($_GET['w'])){
    include($_GET['w'] . ".htm");
}
```

Of course, you'd want a little filtering of the $_GET var too to make sure it doesn't get something you don't want there. Maybe like this.

```
$acceptable_values = array("some","acceptable","values");
if(!empty($_GET['w']) && in_array($_GET['w'],$acceptable_values) ){
    include($_GET['w'] . ".htm");
}
```

As I'm sure you are aware, passing variables directly into include statements or database queries is a TERRIBLE idea. See here for why in this case.

http://websec.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/exploiting-php-file-inclusion-overview/

Comment: if your going to do a $acceptable_values array you may as well map it directly I an another posted.

Comment: yes, but with an array of acceptable values, it will not allow someone to exploit the vulnerabilities present in PHP's include function.

Comment: i don't understand, my idea lists allowed files also, but seems easier to manage

Comment: Sorry, I was apparently typing when you submitted. I disagree on the management though, with this answer, you only have to change one thing to accept new files and links on the pages. Plus, semantically naming files makes much more sense than trying to keep track of 1 => a or b or c or.....

Comment: the files and variables were named such purely for illustrative purposes. I am not disagreeing with your answer, and it may well be the better and/or safer one, but I went with an answer that both worked, and visually made sense to me. My dyslexia makes grasping all this a bit of a challenge at times. But thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a few things, lets take a look at some of them.

```
<?php
$webpage = '';
if(isset($_GET['w']))
  $webpage = strtolower($_GET['w']);

switch($webpage)
{
  case 'b':
    include '2.html';
    break;
  case 'c':
    include '3.html';
    break;
  case 'd':
    include '4.html';
    break;
  default:
    include '1.html';
    break;
}
```

Or we could use arrays

```
<?php
$webpage = '';
if(isset($_GET['w']))
  $webpage = strtolower($_GET['w']);

$included_pages = array(
  'a' => '1.htm',
  'b' => '2.htm',
  'c' => '3.htm',
  'd' => '4.htm',
);

// Check inside our array
if(array_key_exists($webpage, $includes))
{
  include $included_pages[$webpage];
}
else
{
  // Couldn't find the site
  include '1.htm';
}
```